# Sql Pivoting with Two Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am stuck in pivoting below issue in sql, main table mentioned below

```
|PLACE| DATE_1  |ID | FQ | PLAN|
---------------------------------
Alpha |01-03-16 | A | 100| YES |
Alpha |01-03-16 | A | 50 | YES |
Alpha |02-03-16 | A | 10 | YES |
BETA  |02-03-16 | C | 80 | YES |
BETA  |02-03-16 | D | 9  | YES |
BETA  |03-03-16 | D | 11 | YES |
BETA  |03-03-16 | E | 13 | YES |
--------------------------------
```

But need output in below format

```
        |Sum of FQ | Plan      |Sum of FQ  | Plan      |
| Place |ID |01-03-16  | 01-03-16  | 02-03-16  | 02-03-16  | 
| Alaph |A  |100       | YES       | 10        | NO        |
| Alaph |B  |50        | YES       |           |           |
| Beta  |C  |          |           | 80        | NO        |
```

Comment: Do you want two lines of header. If yes then consider doing this in application side

Comment: Yes I want two header for same date with quantity and plan. Please help, I   am new in sql

Comment: Anyone here to help ???

Comment: Two lines of header is not possible in SQL

Comment: I dont need two lines of header first header is just for information.

Comment: Pls help on the same

Comment: Your output makes not sense.  Were does `Alaph` come from?  What happened to IDs D and E?  How do "NO"s appear in the `Plan` column?

Comment: Yes my mistake, The output should be all yes as plan and I have not mentioned D and E but I believe you understand my problem. I need the output in this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output makes no sense, given the input data.  I am going to guess that you want conditional aggregation:

```
select place, id,
       max(case when date_1 = '2016-03-01' then fq end) as fq_20160301,
       max(case when date_1 = '2016-03-01' then plan end) as plan_20160301,
       max(case when date_1 = '2016-03-02' then fq end) as fq_20160302,
       max(case when date_1 = '2016-03-02' then plan end) as plan_20160302
from t
group by place, id;
```

Note that this uses ISO standard date constants.  If you are storing dates as a string (which is a really bad idea), then you'll need to adapt the logic for your data.